# ElasticSearch: Complex filter by nested document

Tags: elasticsearch

I have following document structure:

```
{
    product_name: "Product1",
    product_id: 1,
    ...,
    articles: [
        {
            article_name: 'Article 101',
            id: 101,
            some_param: 10,
            clients: []
        },
        {
            article_name: 'Article 102',
            id: 102,
            some_param: 11,
            clients: [
                {
                    client_id: 10001,
                    client_name: "some client 1001" 
                }
                ...
            ]
        }
    ]
},

{
    product_name: "Product2",
    product_id: 2,
    ...,
    articles: [
        {
            article_name: 'Article 101',
            id: 101,
            some_param: 10,
            clients: []
        },
        {
            article_name: 'Article 102',
            id: 102,
            some_param: 10,
            clients: [
                {
                    client_id: 10001,
                    client_name: "some client 1001" 
                }
                ...
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to get documents (product) ONLY if some of its articles match 2 conditions (single article should match both conditions): articles.some_param = 10 AND articles.clients.client_id = 10001

So I need to get only product with id 2.

I'm using this query now, which is incorrect (and I know why), because it fetches both documents:

```
{
   "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "articles.clients.id": 10001
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "articles.some_param": 10
          }
        }
      ]              
    }
  }
}
```

How can I write query which gets **only** products which has at least 1 article **which matches both conditions**: articles.some_param = 10 AND articles.clients.client_id = 10001

e.g., **to get Product with ID 2 only?**

Comment: You need to have nested types to make it work the way you want. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

Comment: They are already set up as nested types. I believe this problem is not related to nested types. Above query behaves as it should, but it does not fit my requirements. "Get product which has at least 1 article which matches both conditions: articles.some_param = 10 AND articles.clients.client_id = 10001")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
{
 "query": {
  "nested": {
    "path": "articles",
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
              {
                 "term": {
                     "articles.some_param": {
                         "value": 10
                       }
                     }
               },
               {
                 "nested": {
                     "path": "articles.clients",
                        "query": {
                          "term": {
                               "articles.clients.id":{ 
                                 "value": 10001
                            }
                         }
                       }
                  }
               }
           ]
        }
      }
    }
   }
 }
```

UPDATE:
Try wrap second query to bool.

```
{
 "query": {
  "nested": {
    "path": "articles",
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
              {
                 "term": {
                     "articles.some_param": {
                         "value": 10
                       }
                     }
               },
               {
                 "bool":{
                   "must" : [
                     {
                     "nested": {
                     "path": "articles.clients",
                        "query": {
                          "term": {
                               "articles.clients.id":{ 
                                 "value": 10001
                            }
                         }
                       }
                     }
                    }
                  ]
                 }
               }
           ]
        }
      }
    }
   }
 }
```

p.s. I could be mistaken with a path on the second nested query. Just couldn't check. So you can play around with the path on the second query.

p.p.s. The filter is not the query what you need. It does not calculate the scores

Comment: It does not work. I still get both products with this query. I need to get only second one

Comment: You can wrap second nested query with bool query. I will update and you can see. BTW is good to see your mapping.

Comment: Seems 2nd one works, thanks!  (I do not need to calculate scores)

Comment: @moreo you can accept this answer if the suggestion worked for you.